# Mysql automatic update on Linux servers

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, update

We are running a couple of shared host linux servers and a private one. 
We are running cPanel/WHM licenses under them.

The predicament I am facing is :

How can I run the following command automatically ?

mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --optimize --all-databases

The problem is that I am prompted for the root password, but I would like to run this command automatically and the password prompt intrerupts this process.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your root credentials in a file that only the root user can access.  Then simply pass the credentials filename.

```
mysqlcheck --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/root.cnf  --auto-repair --check --optimize --all-databases
```

/etc/mysql/root.cnf

```
[client]
host     = servername.domain.tld
user     = backup
password = strongpassword
```

This doesn't create a huge security vulnerability so long as `/etc/mysql/root.cnf` is only readable by root since the root user could easily reset the mysql passwords without needing any mysql credentials at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the required password either in the `[client]` section of your ~/.my.cnf or an additional config file you specify with `--defaults-extra-file=path/to/yourconfig.cnf`

For more details, please refer to the [option-files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html) segment of the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could just supply the password on the commandline. Of course this has some privacy/security issues.

```
mysqlcheck -uroot -pPASSWORD --auto-repair --check --optimize --all-databases
```